# How to find the object where property values match in two nested objects? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, search

I have two airport datasets - one stored locally and another one fetched from a server.

The local dataset, `airports`, has around 45,000 individual objects, where each object has the following structure:

```
  {
    "ident": "AYPY",
    "type": "large_airport",
    "name": "Port Moresby Jacksons International Airport",
    "latitude_deg": -9.443380356,
    "longitude_deg": 147.2200012,
    "iso_country": "PG"
  },
```

The fetched dataset is created using the `createDestinationObject(title)`, which fetches the related data from the `title` page and stores it in the `finalList` variable. This is how it looks:

```
  {
    "ICAO": "AYPY",
    "name": "Port Moresby Jacksons International Airport",
    "latitude": 0,
    "longitude": 0,
  },
```

The fetched dataset lacks coordinates (hence the placeholder zeroes). I want to take the coordinates from the `airports` dataset by matching `airports.ident` with `finalList.ICAO`, as they both are standard ICAO codes for airports. Then I assign the `latitude_deg` and `longitude_deg` values from the matching `airports` item to the `latitude` and `longitude` properties of the `finalList` item.

To try and solve this, I used a nested for loop where each `finalList` item is looped through the `airports` dataset, and if the ICAO code matches, it assigns the coordinates. The code works, but The problem is that it takes quite some time (even up to 20-30 seconds if `finalList` dataset has >300 objects). Is there any way to solve this faster, without looping every `finalList` item through each of the +40k items in the `airports` dataset?

```
import airports from './airports.json';

async function assignCoordinates(title) {
  var finalList = await createDestinationObject(title);
  for (var destination in finalList) {
    for (var airport in airports) {
      if (finalList[destination].ICAO === airports[airport].ident) {
        finalList[destination].latitude = airports[airport].latitude_deg;
        finalList[destination].longitude = airports[airport].longitude_deg;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(finalList);
}

var title = "Vilnius_Airport";
assignCoordinates(title);
```

I am extremely new to Javascript, so my code might be sloppy in general, don't hesitate to critique.

EDIT:

To give more information, `airports` is stored locally and imported into the .js file.

`finalList` is a list of destinations (airports) from the `title` airport.
The `createDestinationObject(title)` function:

1. Fetches the wikipedia section list from the `title` page.
2. Finds the section where destinations are listed.
3. Fetches the wikitext from this section and stringifies it.
4. Filters the text to find invididual airports and their pagenames.
5. Fetches the summary of each of the individual airports and uses regexp to find the ICAO code in the summary or the infobox.
6. returns a nested object where `finalList.ICAO` is the fetched ICAO code; `finalList.name` is the airport name from the destination section wikitext; `finalList.longitude` and `finalList.latitude` are placeholder properties to store coordinate data. There are as many objects in `finalList` as there are destinations from the `title` airport, each object being one destination airport.

The `createDestinationObject(title)` function itself takes maybe 1-2 seconds to run.

Comment: paste more data. where is `finalList` or `airports` defined

Comment: I edited the post to include some additional information about the datasets.

Answer (score 0):

A better strategy to improve the complexity of visiting the airports array again and again for each destination, you could first spend an entire visit of its elements just for the sake of creating a map that will bind each `.ident` value to the corresponding airport object.

Once you have that map, you can just perform your algorithm that for each destination in the array returned from the api fetch, it picks the corresponding airport just by doing `airportsMap[destination.ICAO]`, and if found, sets its latitude and longitude accordingly.

The strategy I used to make such map is:

```
let airportsMap = Object.assign({}, ...airports.map((a) => ({[a.ident]: a})));
```

That just assign to an empty object all the properties (key-value pairs) coming from `airports.map`

```js
var airports = [
  {
    "ident": "AYPY",
    "type": "large_airport",
    "name": "Port Moresby Jacksons International Airport",
    "latitude_deg": -9.443380356,
    "longitude_deg": 147.2200012,
    "iso_country": "PG"
  },
  {
    "ident": "ZHHE",
    "type": "large_airport",
    "name": "Another International Airport",
    "latitude_deg": -65.3422234,
    "longitude_deg": 143.653453,
    "iso_country": "US"
  },
];

const createDestinationObject = (title) => {
  return [{
      "ICAO": "AYPY",
      "name": "Port Moresby Jacksons International Airport",
      "latitude": 0,
      "longitude": 0,
    },
    {
      "ICAO": "notexisting",
      "name": "...",
      "latitude": 0,
      "longitude": 0,
    },
  ];
};


//this will create a map where each airport is indexed by ICAO
let airportsMap = Object.assign({}, ...airports.map((a) => ({[a.ident]: a})));

function assignCoordinates(title) {
  var finalList = createDestinationObject(title);
  for (let destination of finalList) {
    if (Object.hasOwn(airportsMap, destination.ICAO)) {
      const airport = airportsMap[destination.ICAO];
      destination.latitude = airport.latitude_deg;
      destination.longitude = airport.longitude_deg;
    }
  }
  return finalList;
}

var title = "bogus";
const o = assignCoordinates(title);
console.log(o);
```

Comment: Thank you, that does look a lot more elegant than what I had. However, I tried timing executions of both the old and the new version and I do not see any significant reduction in time. For me, at least, the execution time is practically equal.

Comment: Well I did a blind shot :) anyway I'm quite confident that approach will save some execution cycles.. but maybe the data set is not big enough to make any difference in human time. About the rest I can't see any other spot for improvement. There are just some more snob ways to loop the arrays but here it would be just a waste of ego showing off :D as long as you can avoid control flow nesting it's always a good reason BUT not when everything just becomes obscure to understand